# Visual Studio 2010 intellisense problem

Tags: visual-studio-2010, file, path

I have the following intellisense problem, which only occurs in the Release configuration, even though both Debug and Release use the exact same file paths.

[image]

I've never had problems like this with Visual C++ 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that header is in the include path for the project? That's what it sounds like. The preprocessor is not parsing Window.hpp because it isn't being told to find it. Right clicking on your project and setting extra include directories should fix it.